# How to multibind data and StringFormat in a datagrid column?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, string-formatting

I have a WPF `DataGrid` with numeric columns that are initially formatted without decimals.

The user has a checkbox to select the numeric format to show 0 or 2 decimal places. Below is shown the xaml for the column.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Qty" Width="40" IsReadOnly="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource EditCell}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemQuantity, StringFormat={}{0:#}}" TextAlignment="Right" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox x:Name="textbox"  BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="LightYellow">
                <Binding Path="ItemQuantity" StringFormat="N0" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <c:DecimalRangeRule Min="0" Max="999999.99"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How can I change the column `StringFormat` setting when the checkbox is changed?

**EDIT: Solution**

I used a MultiConverter (as suggested by nit) to select the format based on whether the checkbox is checked:

```
//==========================================================================
public class NumericFormatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private const string FormatN0 = "{0:#,##0;-#,##0; }";
    private const string FormatN2 = "{0:#,##0.00;-#,##0.00; }";

    public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        if ( values[0] == null ) return string.Empty;

        decimal num = 0;
        Decimal.TryParse( values[0].ToString(), out num );

        string format = FormatN0;
        bool isSmallValue = (values[1] == null ? false : (bool)values[1]);
        if ( isSmallValue ) format = FormatN2;

        return String.Format( format, num );
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack( object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        decimal num = 0;
        Decimal.TryParse( value.ToString(), out num );

        object[] objects = new object[1] {num};
        return objects;
    }
}
```

The DataGridTemplateColumn changed to use MultiBinding:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Qty" Width="40" IsReadOnly="False"  CellStyle="{StaticResource EditCell}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NumericFormat}">
                <Binding Path="GroupQuantity" />
                <Binding ElementName="chkSmallValue" Path="IsChecked"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>

    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="LemonChiffon" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" >
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NumericFormat}"  UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding Path="GroupQuantity" />
            <Binding ElementName="chkSmallValue" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Did you consider using IValueConverter? You can use boolean property bounded to checkbox in the converter to return the formatted string from the converter.

Comment: As @nit pointed out you can't change StringFormat easily but you could change the whole Binding e.g. within a Trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As StringFormat is not a dependancy property you can not bind it to any value to change it. 
In order to change it, you will have to find your TextBlock in the visualtree of cell and then change the StringFormat of the BindingExpression in code behind. But this method stinks.

What you can do is to not use StringFormat instead use a MultiValueConverter to multibind the TextBlock.Text to Checkbox IsChecked property and the ItemQuantity. Within the converter you can return the formatted string depending on IsChecked of checkbox

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'll have to investigate to see how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the binding in code using the Checkbox's 'Checked' and 'Unchecked' events.

```
private void HandleCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var binding = new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath("ItemQuantity"),
        StringFormat = "{0:0.00}"
    };
    textBoxName.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
}

private void HandleUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var binding = new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath("ItemQuantity"),
        StringFormat = "{0:0}"
    };
    textBoxName.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

}
```

Comment: I need to access the binding properties from a textbox that resides in a DataGrid column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EventToCommandTrigger which will take you down to your ViewModel in there you can change Change the decimal places in your ItemQuantity.

Doing this in your ViewModel will allow you to write unit tests around the functionality for testing purposes.